# How to get good barley texture

Tags: barley

I have had barley a few times where each pearl is light, slightly dry and separate. When I've cooked it at home I get a very gummy, clumpy texture.

I have been cooking it by rinsing the barley, adding to cold water, bringing to a boil and then simmering for about 50 minutes. I use 1:3 barley to water.

Any tips for a better end product?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Do you know if your barley is pearl barley, or hulled barley?

Comment: The barley I am using is pearl.

Comment: I always add a bit of fat(butter) and salt to mine.  It turns out probably how you want.  Also, if you don't mind draining, add more liquid and then drain off the excess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cooking, I drain the barley in a colander then boil the kettle and "rinse" the cooked barley with boiling water as if I was rinsing the starch off cooked pasta. This makes sure that my cooked barley is less clumpy.